# Bash tab completion like ncftp?

Tags: linux, bash

In `ncftp` tab completion only shows the differences of matched files. E.g. with the following files

```
file123 file125 aa
```

then typing `ls fil` will first complete to `ls file12` and show

```
3 5
```

**Question**

Can the same be done in Bash?

Answer (score 1):

BASH supports tab-completion which is fairly robust. It is implemented through `bash_completion`. However, be aware that the way bash_completion is configured will depend on what options are set by default by your distribution. As for its basic functionality, it is exactly as you describe for `ncftp`. When a partial name is entered on the command line and `tab` is pressed, then a list of name-matched files are displayed. Once you have entered enough characters to make the name unique, `tab` will complete entry of the unique filename on the command line.

Linux also provides `ls`, but its behavior is not the same as you describe for `ncftp`. ls will return the names of files and directories that match the pattern you specified. By default, the name you provide to `ls` is not expanded. Meaning if you have `file123` and `file125` in a directory and issue the command `ls file`, you will be greeted by the error `ls: cannot access bash: No such file or directory`. But providing a wildcard (filename globbing) with `ls file*` will return both names.

If you have additional specific questions. Just leave a comment and we will do our best to help.